# How do I open camera from tab bar?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I figured out how to open the camera from a button, however I can't do it from the tab.

What I would like to happen is similar to the blue tab icon on Instagram. When you click it, it goes to camera.

Comment: Hint: Use the tab bar delegate to know when a tab is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Press CMD + N and create a new Cocoa Touch Class via iOS -> Source. Give it a class name and make it a subclass of UITabBarController.

Then copy and paste the following code into a subclass of UITabBarController:

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
    //  Set camera index to the index on your tabbar
    let cameraIndex =　<#T##Int#>
    if item == (self.tabBar.items! as [UITabBarItem])[cameraIndex] {
        //  Call Camera
    }
}
```

Comment: *UITabBarController file* — what is that? Do you mean a UITabBarController subclass?

Comment: Correct. Press CMD + N and create a new Cocoa Touch Class via iOS -> Source. Give it a class name and make it a subclass of UITabBarController. Then in Storyboard, assign that class file (the name you gave it) to the UITabBarController in your storyboard. Once you do that, copy and paste the code I gave you into the class file and follow the instructions in the comment.

Comment: please fix your answer. btw: Swift does not force you to use a file per each class.

Comment: *Cocoa Touch Class* is just an item in the Xcode wizard. It does not really exist. As you are not forced to create a subclass via this wizard, why not just say "Subclass UITabBarController"?